# What does the phrase "low conversion from large exposure" mean?

Tags: phrases

This is the sentrence from the text about email and displaying advirtising.  What does the phrase "low conversion from large exposure" mean?

This is the nature of advertising, of course; about awareness and relatively low conversion from large exposure.
https://econsultancy.com/blog/67464-why-email-is-the-king-of-one-to-one-marketing

I found the definition of the phrase "advertising awareness" which means "Extent to which the intended audience or targeted customers are aware of an advertising message".

As for "conversion" I guess it relates to conversion marketing - the act of converting site visitors into paying customers.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_marketing

I would appreciate if someone explain this in simple words. Thank you

Comment: Consider: "*...of course; **it's** about awareness...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Let's say you produce a piece of advertising and 1 million people see/hear your ad (for instance by television, internet, billboard, email, radio).  You have an "exposure" of 1 million: 1 million people were aware of your message.
- The process of making the people who saw the ad into a paying customer is called "conversion".

Let's say in my fictitious example, of the 1 million people who saw your ad, some contact you and you talk to them. Of those whom you talked to, many are not interested and others want to go forward and learn more about your product. Maybe they see or touch the product, get pricing and service information and maybe they are offered the opportunity to try/test it. Out of this last group, some don't like the product and others do. Of those who do, a number of them may not be ready to buy for miscellaneous reasons, including financial reasons... or maybe they want to shop some more, and they proceed to decline to buy now.

Eventually, say 10 people out of the 1 million who saw the advertising buy from you.
The "conversion" ratio is: 10 divided by 1 million or 0.0001 (0.001%).
You can then say that you had low conversion (0.001%) from large exposure (1 million).